# How can I let a set retain all strings that contain my specified substring in java?

Tags: java, set, substring, hashset

I use a hashset for a dictionary. Now I would like to filter out words that do not start with my substring. So it should be something like this:

```
String word = 'ab';
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(word);
boolean result = lexiconSet.retainAll(list);
```

And instead of this resulting in the lexicon only containing the word 'ab', I would like to keep all words beginning with 'ab'. How can I do this?

I know I can convert the set to a string arraylist, and loop over all elements to see if the strings starts with 'ab', but since I think this can be time consuming and not efficient, I would like to hear better solutions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why convert to ArrayList? You can loop over the Set itself.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, life is easy:

```
list.removeIf(s -> !s.startsWith("ab"));
```

This will remove all elements that *don't* begin with "ab".

Note that you can use `values()` to retrieve the map's values and work directly on them, without the need to convert to `ArrayList`.

Comment: You mean `lexiconSet.removeIf(…)`…